# What is wrong with my code that removes vowels from strings?

Tags: c, string

I'm new to programming and I've decided to do some simple programming exercises.
The challenge is to remove all vowels from a user inputted string.
I've already wrote the code and I don't know why it isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool isVowel(char ch)
{
    char charToBeTested = tolower(ch);
    if(charToBeTested == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char formattedString[80];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", &formattedString);

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(formattedString); i++)
    {
        if(isVowel(formattedString[i]) == true)
        {
            formattedString[i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    printf("%s", formattedString);
    return 0;
}
```

All it is supposed to do is check every character in the string and see if it's a vowel. If it's a vowel, replace the current character with a space. I will write the function to remove the spaces later.

All help is appreciated, sorry for being such a noob!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! No need to apologize for being a noob -- we were all there once. Anyway, what problem are you having? What's the error?

Comment: You should remove the `&` before `formattedString` in the call to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
if (charToBeTested == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u') {
    ...
}
```

C interprets this as

```
if ((charToBeTested == 'a') || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u') {
    ...
}
```

Here, the `||` operator is being applied directly to the character literals `'e'`, `'i'`, etc. Since C treats any nonzero value as "true," this statement always evaluates to true.

To fix this, try rewriting it like this:

```
if (charToBeTested == 'a' || 
    charToBeTested == 'e' || 
    charToBeTested == 'i' || 
    charToBeTested == 'o' || 
    charToBeTested == 'u') {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, use a `switch` statement:

```
switch (charToBeTested) {
    case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
        return true;
    default:
       return false;
}
```

Also, you might want to use `tolower` so that the testing is done case-insensitively.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to test each alternative separately:

```
 char c = tolower(ch);
 if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
```

Your original code is:

```
 if (charToBeTested == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')
```

The compiler evaluates that as:

```
 if ((charToBeTested == 'a') || true)
```

because `'e'` is not zero and any expression which is not zero is true.
If it optimizes really thoroughly, can deduce that the whole expression will always be true, regardless of the value of `charToBeTested`, and hence it can reduce the entire function to `return true` (without ever needing to call `tolower()`.  If it was a static function, it could even eliminate the function call altogether.  Whether any compiler would actually be that aggressive is open to debate.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

```
if(charToBeTested == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')
```

correct is:

```
if(charToBeTested == 'a' || charToBeTested == 'e' || charToBeTested == 'i' || charToBeTested == 'o' || charToBeTested == 'u')
```

Or, you can create static table, like:

```
char vowels[0x100] = {
  ['a'] = 1,
  ['e'] = 1,
  ['i'] = 1,
  ['o'] = 1,
  ['u'] = 1,
};
```

And test by:

```
if(vowels[(unsigned char)charToBeTested])
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helps me understand where the error was! I knew it was some simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to rewrite your isVowel function to something like:

```
bool isVowel(char ch)
{
    char charToBeTested = tolower(ch);
    if(charToBeTested == 'a') {
        return true;
    } else if(charToBeTested == 'e') {
        return true;
    } else if(charToBeTested == 'i') {
        return true;
    } else if(charToBeTested == 'o') {
        return true;
    } else if(charToBeTested == 'u') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a switch statement to do the same thing, like this:

```
bool isVowel(char ch)
{
    char charToBeTested = tolower(ch);
    switch(charToBeTested) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to everyones answer; as they say, you need to fix your testing criteria.
Also, don't forget to check for the Uppercase version too:

```
if (charToBeTested == 'a' || 
    charToBeTested == 'e' || 
    charToBeTested == 'i' || 
    charToBeTested == 'o' || 
    charToBeTested == 'u' ||
    charToBeTested == 'A' || 
    charToBeTested == 'E' || 
    charToBeTested == 'I' || 
    charToBeTested == 'O' || 
    charToBeTested == 'U') {
    ...
}
```